# How to find an item in core data backed table view and make it selected

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

When the app is launching at first there is no selected cell in the table view. Only after the user tapped one of it.

I know from the cora data database which managed object is the selected one but how could I find it and make it selected/highlighted etc in the table view?

Actually I need the index of that item in the tableview.

To store the last selected cell's index and store it is not a good solution as the database could change so I have to find it and meantime get the it's index.

Comment: If you know the selected object, you can test for it in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and when it matches you set the cell as selected

Comment: Yes, I thought about it but I dropped this idea as it will slow down the process in the most speed sensitive part of the cell building, so this could cause erratic movement when scrolling with bigger database, and I need this just for the first time.

Comment: @MariusFalkenbergWaldal comment is the way to go. Why do you think you would have performance issues?

Comment: @MariusFalkenbergWaldal Ok I bend to go with your solution especially after Paul.s comment and try to forget the performance issue, maybe it's just prejudice. Anyway how do you set the cell selected? My guess is selectRowAtIndexPath: as the setSelected couldn't work here...

Comment: Careful of preoptimization. Test both approaches, and see if there is actually a performance hit (which I doubt). Only then try to optimize it :-)

Comment: And yes; selectRowAtIndexPath is the way to go. Let me know if this works for you and I will write it up in an answer for later reference and so that you can upvote and accept answer :-)

Comment: @Marius Falkenberg Waldal yes selectRowAtIndexPath: works and I haven't found performance issue, so this is the solution...